# PyQt4 Windows - Toolbar Actions don't work. How can I fix them?

Tags: python, windows, action, pyqt4, toolbar

I have made a program that has a Toolbar with a few actions on it in Linux. The Toolbar and its actions work perfectly on a Linux OS, but when I run the code on a Windows machine, the actions just don't work. Everything looks the same as on Linux(yes I have PyQt4 installed on the Windows machine), even the toolbar, but when I click an item on the toolbar it just doesn't execute the given handler.  I tried and made a basic PyQt4 program with a toolbar only to test if the bug is because of my program, but the results are the same. Here's the basic example program which doesn't work.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

def aTest(obj = None):
    print "If this appears, the action works."

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QtGui.QMainWindow()
toolBar = w.addToolBar("toolbar")

action = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon("path to icon here"), "testAction", w)
w.connect(action, QtCore.SIGNAL("activated()"), aTest)

toolBar.addAction(action)

w.show()

app.exec_()
```

This code works on Linux without a problem, but on Windows the actions just don't react when activated. Ignore the typos in the code.

OS: Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit (doesn't work on XP either)

Python version: Python 2.7

PyQt4 version: PyQt-Py2.7-x86-gpl-4.8.4-1

I hope someone out there can help me. I thank you all for your interest and help!

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's odd that it works in Linux, because I can only get it work on Windows by changing

```
w.connect(action, QtCore.SIGNAL("activated()"), aTest)
```

to

```
w.connect(action, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), aTest)
```

The [QAction class reference](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qaction.html) only lists `changed()`, `hovered()`, `toggled()` and `triggered()` as valid signals.  Unfortunately I don't have a Linux box handy to test things out further.

Comment: Thank you for replying! This solved my problem. However, I can guarantee you that, on my Linux machine at least(Ubuntu 10.10), the program works even with activated() as the signal. I find it strange too. Well, thanks again for your reply! Have a nice day!

Comment: I ran across [this thread](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/5862-What-is-the-difference-between-the-activated%28%29-and-triggered%28%29-SIGNALs-for-a-QAction).  Apparently, `activated()` was used in Qt3 and is still around for some versions for compatibility.